# Visual studio not recognizing System

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Probably a simple question but I'm just coming back to using visual studio after years of intellij.

Visual studio recognizes none of the classes from the system namespace. Something is clearly wrong with my dependencies, but I have no idea what or where to find what's wrong. This is in Visual Studio Community 2019 if that helps.

[image]

If I have to reinstall .net or something like that please instruct me well, made mistakes there before and I find it really hard to know what I'm doing in that department.

Comment: Try opening a command prompt at the root of the project, execute dotnet restore. Back in Visual Studio perform a build, see if this solve the issue.

Comment: Just clean the project and that'll fix the issue. To clean the solution, go to Build > Clean Solution.

Comment: Both didn't work, going to try again after setting the target framework (wasn't aware that needs to be set by hand).

Comment: YES after setting the framework, running `dotnet restore` in the command prompt solved it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to solve the problem is opening a command prompt at the root of the project, execute [`dotnet restore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore#description).

The `dotnet restore` command uses NuGet to restore dependencies as well as project-specific tools that are specified in the project file.